# Does Windows have an equivalent to Linux/FreeBSD's `RESOLVE_BENEATH` and `O_RESOLVE_BENEATH`?

Tags: windows, winapi

I want to open a file, while ensuring that no component of the path goes outside a certain directory.

On Linux, I can accomplish this using `openat2` and `RESOLVE_BENEATH`, and on FreeBSD there is the `O_RESOLVE_BENEATH` flag with `openat`.

Is there any way to achieve the same effect on Windows? Note that this needs to be on a per-call basis — globally restricting my process to a given directory is not useful.

Comment: Possibly, you could [canonicalize the path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/pathcch/nf-pathcch-pathcchcanonicalizeex) first, then check that the resultant path string begins with that of the constraining directory. Not sure how that works for **pure** relative paths (like `../../blob/x.x`) though.

Comment: You could use CreateFile(), followed by GetFinalPathNameByHandle() to get the absolute path of an opened file. -- And to restrict to a directory, use the same method to normalize the directory's name (resolving symlinks), then check if the file's absolute filename starts with the directory's.

Of course, this won't work to ensure *all* parts of the path being inside of your sub-tree (symlinks could jump into- and out-of your tree). - For that, you'd probably need to re-implement path traversal and check the absolute filenames (with symlinks resolved) at every '\' (or '/')

Comment: Hm, it looks like `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` will allow most of what I want (except, of course, for the individual component issue). I think I can accept that as the cost of avoiding needing to roll my own path traversal.

Comment: @use I'm not sure I understand. [`GetFinalPathNameByHandleW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfinalpathnamebyhandlew) returns the *fully resolved* path name. There aren't going to be any symbolic links left, so I'm not sure I understand your concerns.

Comment: @IInspectable `RESOLVE_BENEATH` should cause **any** reference to a path component outside the specified tree to fail. -- If you simply compare the fully resolved paths of the file with the path you want to limit yourself to, then the path you used to open the file might have still containd a symlink that briefly jumped outside of the limited path before jumping back into it:
`ln -s "/a/b" "/limited/a"; ln -s "/limited/b" "/a/b"`. With RESOLVE_BENEATH `/limited`, opening `/limited/a` succeeds and yields `/limited/b`, but should fail (because `/a/b` was used during traversal).